# No se ejecuta el .exe con pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy probando como pasar un script de python a .exe , pero de momento no me sale con algo simple:

en la consola CMD ejecuto estos comandos:

1. pyinstaller mainClass.py
2. pyinstaller -F mainClass.py
3. pyinstaller -w mainClass.py
4. pyinstaller -w -F mainClass.py

Y me genera el .exe , pero al hacer click o ejecutarlo en consola no hace nada.
Alguna sugerencia? Tengo Python version 3.7

***EDIT 2:***

Módulo prueba.py

```
class Foto():

    def muestraImagen(self,img):
        return cv2.imshow("img",img)

    def cambiaFondoBlanco(self,img):
        for x in range(len(img)):
            for y in range(len(img[0])):
                if img[x][y][0]==0:
                    img[x][y] = 255 
        return img

    def convierteEscalaGrises(self,img):
        return cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


    def binarizaImagen(self,imgGris,u1,u2,y):
        return cv2.threshold(imgGris,u1,u2,y)


    def filtroGaussiano(self,imgBinarizada,mask,y):
        return cv2.GaussianBlur(imgBinarizada,mask,y)


    def detectaBordes(self,imgSuavizado,u1,u2):
        return cv2.Canny(imgSuavizado,u1,u2)


    def buscaContornos(self,imgBorde):
        return cv2.findContours(imgBorde.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


    def dibujaContornos(self,imgNormal,imgContorno,u1,l,f1):
        return cv2.drawContours(imgNormal,imgContorno,u1,l,f1)


    def puntosEje(self,imagen, ellipse):
        x1,x2,y1,y2,q,p,m,n = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        puntoCentralX = int(ellipse[0][0])
        puntoCentralY = int(ellipse[0][1])
        for x in range(1000):
            if(imagen[puntoCentralX + x][puntoCentralY] == 255):
                x1 = x
                break

        for x in range(1000):
            if(imagen[puntoCentralX - x][puntoCentralY] == 255):
                x2 = x
                break

        for y in range(1000):
            if(imagen[puntoCentralX][puntoCentralY + y] == 255):
                y1 = y
                break

        for y in range(1000):
            if(imagen[puntoCentralX][puntoCentralY - y] == 255):
                y2 = y
                break 

        if(x1>x2):
            m = x1
            n = x2
        else:
            m = x2
            n = x1

        if(y1>y2):
            q = y1
            p = y2
        else: 
            q = y2
            p = y1

        return (m,n,q,p)

    def calculoVolumen(self,puntos):
        m, n, q, p = puntos[0], puntos[1], puntos[2], puntos[3]
        v1 = (1/6)*math.pi*n*math.pow(p+q, 2)
        v2 = (1/3)*math.pi*m*math.pow(p,2)
        v3 = (1/3)*math.pi*m*math.pow(q,2)
        return (v1+v2+v3)*math.pow(10, -6)




foto = Foto()
# Cargamos la imagen
img = cv2.imread("img/mango-de-frente.png", 1)
img2 = cv2.imread("img/mango-top.jpg",1)
img3 = cv2.imread("img/orange.jpg",1)
naranja = cv2.imread("img/naranja-frente.jpg", 1)
manzana = cv2.imread("img/manzanaFondoBlancoo.png",1)
img = cv2.resize(img, (320, 320)) 
manzana = foto.cambiaFondoBlanco(manzana)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("orange", img3) 
cv2.imshow("manzana",manzana)



gris =  foto.convierteEscalaGrises(img)
gris2 = foto.convierteEscalaGrises(img2)
gris3 = foto.convierteEscalaGrises(img3)
grisManzana = foto.convierteEscalaGrises(manzana)

ret,thresh = foto.binarizaImagen(gris, 244, 255, 0)
ret2,thresh2 = foto.binarizaImagen(gris2, 244, 255, 0)
ret3,thresh3 = foto.binarizaImagen(gris3, 244, 255, 0)
ret4,threshManzana = foto.binarizaImagen(grisManzana, 220, 255, 0)



cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh) 
cv2.imshow("thresh2", thresh2)
cv2.imshow("thresh3", thresh3)
cv2.imshow("threshManzana", threshManzana)


gauss = foto.filtroGaussiano(thresh, (5,5), 0)
gauss2 = foto.filtroGaussiano(thresh2, (5,5), 0)
gauss3 = foto.filtroGaussiano(thresh3, (5,5), 0)
gaussManzana = foto.filtroGaussiano(threshManzana, (5,5), 0)


cv2.imshow("suavizado", gauss)
cv2.imshow("suavizado2", gauss2)
cv2.imshow("suavizado3", gauss3)
cv2.imshow("suavizadoManzana", gaussManzana)



canny = foto.detectaBordes(gauss, 0, 255)
canny2 = foto.detectaBordes(gauss2, 0, 255)
canny3 = foto.detectaBordes(gauss3, 0, 255)
cannyManzana = foto.detectaBordes(gaussManzana, 0, 255)



cv2.imshow("canny", canny)
cv2.imshow("canny2", canny2)
cv2.imshow("canny3", canny3)
cv2.imshow("cannyManzana", cannyManzana)



(contornos,_) = foto.buscaContornos(canny)
(contornos2,_) = foto.buscaContornos(canny2)
(contornos3,_) = foto.buscaContornos(canny3)
(contornosManzana,_) = foto.buscaContornos(cannyManzana)


foto.dibujaContornos(img, contornos, -1, (0,0,255), 2)
foto.dibujaContornos(img2, contornos2, -1, (0,0,255), 2)
foto.dibujaContornos(img3, contornos3, -1, (0,0,255), 2)
foto.dibujaContornos(manzana, contornosManzana, -1, (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow("contornos", img)
cv2.imshow("contornos2", img2)
cv2.imshow("contornos3", img3)
cv2.imshow("contornosManzana", manzana)



#momentos y centroide de la imagen de frente
m = cv2.moments(thresh)
print(m)
cX = int(m["m10"] / m["m00"])
cY = int(m["m01"] / m["m00"])

#momentos y centroide de la imagen de arriba
m2 = cv2.moments(thresh2)
print(m2)
cX2 = int(m2["m10"] / m2["m00"])
cY2 = int(m2["m01"] / m2["m00"])

centroide=cv2.circle(canny, (cX, cY), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.circle(canny2, (cX2, cY2), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.imshow("Image", canny)
cv2.imshow("Image2", canny2)


cnt = contornos[0]
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
print("Area",area)
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
imagene=cv2.ellipse(img,ellipse,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("Imagen del mango con elipse",imagene)
print("Eje mayor y eje menor",ellipse[1])
print("(x,y)",ellipse[0])

cnt3 = contornos3[0]
area3 = cv2.contourArea(cnt3)
print("Area3",area3)
ellipse3 = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt3)
imagene3=cv2.ellipse(img3,ellipse3,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("Imagen de la naranja con elipse",imagene3)
print("Eje mayor y eje menor",ellipse3[1])
print("(x,y)",ellipse3[0])

cntManzana = contornosManzana[0]
areaManzana = cv2.contourArea(cntManzana)
print("Area3 de la manzana --> ",areaManzana)
ellipseManzana = cv2.fitEllipse(cntManzana)
imagenManzana=cv2.ellipse(manzana,ellipseManzana,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow("Imagen de la manzana con elipse",imagenManzana)
print("Eje mayor y eje menor",ellipseManzana[1])
print("(x,y)",ellipseManzana[0])

def redondez(contorno):
    cnt= contorno[0]
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    perimetro = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    print(area, perimetro)
    resultado = 4* math.pi *(area / perimetro)
    return resultado

print("La redondez es", redondez(contornos))

def excentricidad(ellipse):
    ejeMayor = ellipse[1][0]
    ejeMenor = ellipse[1][1]
    resultado = math.sqrt(math.pow(ejeMayor, 2) * math.pow(ejeMenor, 2)) / ejeMayor
    return resultado

print("La excentricidad es", excentricidad(ellipseManzana))

def tipoDeFruta(redondez, excentricidad):
    tipo = 0
    if(redondez < 680):
        tipo = "Manzana"
    elif(redondez > 680 and redondez < 820):
        tipo = "Mango"
    else:
        tipo = "Naranja"
    return tipo


rMango = redondez(contornos)
eMango = excentricidad(ellipse)
rNaranja = redondez(contornos3)
eNaranja = excentricidad(ellipse3)
rManzana = redondez(contornosManzana)
eManzana = excentricidad(ellipseManzana)
print("La fruta es:", tipoDeFruta(rMango, eMango))
print("La fruta es:", tipoDeFruta(rNaranja, eNaranja))
print("La fruta es:", tipoDeFruta(rManzana, eManzana))



puntos = foto.puntosEje(canny, ellipse)
puntos3 = foto.puntosEje(canny3, ellipse3)
puntosManzana = foto.puntosEje(cannyManzana,ellipseManzana)


volumen = foto.calculoVolumen(puntos)
volumen3 = foto.calculoVolumen(puntos3)
volumenManzana = foto.calculoVolumen(puntosManzana)

densidadMango = 10.90
masa = densidadMango * volumen
print("La masa estimada del mango es -->",masa,"gramos")

densidadNaranja = 11.00
masaNaranja = densidadNaranja * volumen3
print("La masa estimada de la naranja es -->",masaNaranja,"gramos")

densidadManzana = 10.00
masaManzana = densidadManzana * volumenManzana
print("La masa estimada de la manzana es -->",masaManzana,"gramos")

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Me lanza este error : ValueError: source code string cannot contain null byte

Comment: Supongo que estarás en la ruta del fichero

Comment: Sí , estoy dentro de la carpeta donde está el fichero

Comment: El tema es lo que hace ` mainClass.py`, sobre ese modulo se construye el ejecutable y no sobre `setup.py`. Revisa esto: https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/

Comment: He probado distintos scripts aún poniendolo bien no se ejecuta nada , y en uno de ellos que es el que me interesa salta este error ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes . No sé si requiero de una interfaz gráfica para poder ejecutarlo o no sé. Ando perdido en este tema

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

una forma mas facil para crear ejecutables es con [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) que probe una gui con la cual puedes crear ejecutables de forma mucho mas facil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es necesario que el programa(.exe) tenga una interfaz gráfica para que se pueda ejecutar desde la consola? Porque estoy probando con distintos scripts de python los pasa a .exe , pero en ningún caso me ejecuta nada cuando los ejecuto

Comment: De hecho en uno de ellos me aparece este error ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: ¿Es necesario algo en el código que detecte a la hora de ejecutarlo?

Comment: no necesariamente podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar el codigo que deseas ejecutar ya que si solicitas datos atravez de args debe ejeuctar el exe desde consola

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con el código que quiero ejecutar. Este archivo prueba.py ni si quiera se me pasa a .exe por el error que te he comentado antes. ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: Igualmente aunque se hubiera pasado a .exe , no sé si hubiera ejecutado por si falta algo en el código que desconozco

Comment: tu problema es error el la rutas de las imagenes :v no es problema de la convercion :v

Comment: Error en las rutas? Si ejecuto el programa en eclipse no tengo ningún problema

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres

Comment: la ruta de tus imagenes no existe desde donde tas ejecutando el exe. por lo que veo es una ruta relativa... el exe solo es el codigo de la app no incluye las imagenes!

Comment: No se transforma a .exe me refiero

Comment: copiando las imagenes a la ruta del exe o pasando la imagenes a string base64 y luego volviendo a convertir a la hora de la ejecucion [read base64 with opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754935/read-a-base-64-encoded-image-from-memory-using-opencv-python-library#comments-37914122)

Comment: Si pero me refiero si no se transforma a .exe como voy a copiar las imagenes en la ruta del .exe

Comment: si no se convierte a exe algo esta mal en tu codigo debes corregirlo antes de continuar o reinstalar las librerias atravez de `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall NombreDelPaquete` o crear una nueva pregunta especificando el error y la linea en la que te aparese!

Comment: Cuando ejecuto mi programa en Eclipse no hay ningún problema. No sé a que fallo te puedes referir

Comment: Esto no deberia ser una respuesta, si no un comentario. Asi como esta, es puro SPAM ya que no contesta la pregunta.